# fopen file from windows network location

Tags: c++, c, windows, fopen

I can open files from a mounted network drive, but not from an unmounted one e.g \\mycomp\folder2\hi.bmp

Any work around for this?

Comment: Umm... mount the drive before you try to access files from it?

Comment: Are you forgetting that you need to write `\\` to get a literal backslash in C?

Comment: @R No I was not. Thanks though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3308600/12092048
what is 'r'? in the syntax. of the earlier answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet works for me:

```
char buffer[1000];    
FILE* file;
size_t bytesRead;

file = fopen("\\\\server\\share\\test.dat", "rb");  
if (file != NULL)
{
    bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Also note this excerpt from the [fopen docs (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx):

> **...**
>
> fopen will accept paths that are
>   valid on the file system at the point
>   of execution; ***UNC paths and paths
>   involving mapped network drives are
>   accepted by fopen as long as the
>   system executing the code has access
>   to the share or mapped network drive
>   at the time of execution***. Special care
>   must be taken when constructing paths
>   for fopen to avoid making assumptions
>   about available drives, paths or
>   network shares in the execution
>   environment.
>   **...**

You also need to consider, that the account you are running your program under, needs to have the appropriate access rigths to the file. When you mount the share as a network drive, maybe you are using different credentials to connect. That could cause `fopen` to fail.

Comment: Thanks mate. I thought this was nearly exactly what I tried earlier but its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
fopen("\\\\192.168.1.4\\SharedFolder\\Configfile.txt","r");
```

or

```
 fopen("\\\\ServerName\\SharedFolder\\Configfile.txt","r");
```