# C Windows Add Default Search path for files (fopen...)

Tags: c, winapi

I have written a little interpreter which can run scripts.
For convenience, I associated the file type (.apol) with my interpreter located in "C:\Apol\Interpeter.exe" so whenever I double click a .apol file the Script interpreter will pop up and run this file.

but heres my problem. lets assume my script looks like following:

```
f = openfile("data.txt") //pseudocode
```

of course, windows will look in the directory of "C:\Apol\" first for this file, but what I actually want, is that windows will look in the directory of my Scipt file instead of my Interpreter, is this somehow possible to set up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1746519/2176845

Comment: Are you sure? I happen to have a script interpreter as well and I've just tested it and found the current working directory to be the script path, not the location of the interpreter

Comment: Maybe its the way my interpreter is written :( Ive fixed it with _chdir(path) which changes the working directory to some path (in my case the script)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use Universal Naming Convention Path Syntax in your call to fopen.
See [fopen file from windows network location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308245/fopen-file-from-windows-network-location/3308513#3308513)

Also you will want to find out about the script file the user clicked on, where that is located:

```
int
WINAPI
WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nShowCmd
    );
```

The lpCmdLine has that information for you.